# Pulling monthly Google Search data into Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-trends

Trying to set up a Google Sheet formula to pull historical data on keyword search on Google.

https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=2013-06-21%202023-07-21&q=tesla
or
https://trends.google.com/trends/
along with a search of the word 'tesla'.

This is a source example where there is a monthly proportion to maximum searches (aka peak). I'd like for it to show according to the following scenario.

I enter the word 'tesla' in box A2. In column B it would show the dates (2013-08-01 format) where I currently have the first of the month on each next box in the column starting B2. In column C it would show the value of searches (the link shows proportion, but if it's easier then volume is fine too).

Please let me know if you need further clarification, tried to  as clear as I can but scraping and using Google Sheet formulae is quite new to me. If I could simply copy+paste the code into B2 then that would be optimal.

edit: I'm open to using App Script, only want to use free options.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Script to import data from Google trends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51525640/google-script-to-import-data-from-google-trends)

Comment: This is far too complicated for a single formula.   You'll need a script.